# Update panel and hidden fields in a server control

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, hidden-field, custom-server-controls

I am creating a custom server control and creating an update panel server-side and a few hidden fields **in the server-side**, as follows:

```
UpdatePanel UpdatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
UpdatePanel.ID = "udpReport1";
UpdatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
UpdatePanel.ChildrenAsTriggers = true;
```

Hidden field below:

```
HiddenField HiddenField = new HiddenField();
HiddenField.ID = "hdnField";
UpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(HiddenField);
```

The hidden field values are assigned by JavaScript. Now, when I call __doPostBack() on the update panel using JavaScript, all my hidden fields lose their value as they are reinitialised when rendering my server control. This is a server control so I cannot declare these fields from my .aspx page. I need a way to retain these values when the update panel is posted back. Also, I'm already using __EVENTARGUMENT to store some other values, and require more hidden fields to retain some more values.

Can someone point out how can I retain the hidden field values on posting back the update panel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you set the update panel visiable status(true or false).

Comment: It has nothing to do with the visibility. The update panel is visible and functional, I just need to be able to retain certain server-side generated field values on postback.